# How do I make my variable be the result of two different queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Have been trying this with `UNION` but not having much luck. Not sure how to manage the different parameters in `bind_param` - in one case it is `$user_id`, the other case `$contact_id`.

I have two `SQL` queries:

1.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review_shared INNER JOIN category ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
            INNER JOIN contacts ON review_shared.contact_id = contacts.user_id 
            WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ?"; 

    $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
    $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

    $privateReviews = $stmt2->get_result();
```

2.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review_shared INNER JOIN category ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
            INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.user_id INNER JOIN review
            WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ? AND review.public_or_private = 2"; 

            $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $stmt2->bind_param('i', $contact_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
            $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

            $privateReviews = $stmt2->get_result();
```

How would I make `$privateReviews` be the results of these two queries?

Comment: `$privateReviews[] = $stmt1->get_result(); $privateReviews[] = $stmt2->get_result();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put both objects into an array and access via an index:

```
$privateReviews[] = $stmt1->get_result(); $privateReviews[] = $stmt2->get_result();
```

Or another alternative: you could merge the objects:

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $stmt1->get_result(), (array) $stmt2->get_result();
```

**UPDATE:**

As you're using the array method, you'd need to place a `for` loop around the `while` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    while($row = $privateReviews[$i]->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['DB COLUMN NAME'];
    }
}
```

Also - if both your SQL commands are referencing the same table, and have the same fields - why not try [`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) your queries instead?

Comment: Thanks but further on `while (($row = $privateReviews[]->fetch_assoc())) { etc...}` isn't working.

Comment: You need to specify the index: `$privateReviews[0]->fetch_assoc()` where `0` is the first instance in the array. `1` would be the second instance.

Comment: ok tx for your help, need to go now but will look at it tonight. So it would be something like: `while (($row = $privateReviews[0] Or  $row = $privateReviews[1]  ->fetch_assoc())) {...}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) in sql, especially you execute query to one table.

```php
$sql = "(SELECT a.* FROM review_shared a INNER JOIN category ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
    INNER JOIN contacts ON review_shared.contact_id = contacts.user_id 
    WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ?)
    UNION
    (SELECT b.* FROM review_shared b INNER JOIN category ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
    INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.user_id INNER JOIN review
    WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ? AND review.public_or_private = 2)";

$stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt2->bind_param('ii', $contact_id, $contact_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
$stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

$privateReviews = $stmt2->get_result();
```